# how to declare variable as hash or dictionary type in plpgsql postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

i have data as hash -> key:value

```
cc_to_name_dict = {
"00": "Unknown",
"AW": "Aruba",
"AG": "Antigua and Barbuda",
"AE": "United Arab Emirates"}
```

how to store this data in variable to use it in function like

```
Create  OR REPLACE function convert__gender__gender__from__integer__to__string(gender_int integer)
returns varchar
language plpgsql
as
$$
    DECLARE gender_str varchar;
Begin
    if gender_int = 0 then
        gender_str := 'M';
    elsif gender_int = 1 then
        gender_str := 'F';
    elsif gender_int = 2 then
        gender_str := 'U';
    elsif gender_int is null then
        gender_str := null;
    else
        gender_str := -1;
    end if;

   return gender_str;
End
$$;
```

i need search by key return value from dictionary variable

Comment: Use a `jsonb` variable

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how to make this ? you any example ?